# how file upload works in apache tomcat using primefaces?

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to know what happens when we upload a file using primefaces and using an apache tomcat server. As per my knowledge , before uploading it to a system , tomcat stores temporarily somewhere . Can we see in that temporary folder if upload successful ? if file size is bigger , it throws an error like this .

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/maintenance] threw                 exception
java.io.IOException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. No space left on device
```

Any help ?
thanks in advance .

P.S i am using Unix

Comment: "No space left on device"

Answer (score 1):

I use apache tomcat and this works fine for me:

The form must be  `enctype="multipart/form-data` and add these in `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
<param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>

 <filter>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

In xhtml file:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload">
<p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" fileUploadListener="#{uploadParcelBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|txt)$/"        
        description="Select File"        
        label="Select File" uploadLabel="Upload" cancelLabel="Cancel"        
        validatorMessage="Invalid Format."      
        dragDropSupport="true"      
        multiple="true"      
        update="growl fileList"
        disabled="false"/>
</h:form>
```

In bean side, you can handle uploaded files:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {    
    try {        
    copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());             
    //other logics
    }
    catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();           
    }
```

And the copy method something like:

```
public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {

      String destination="C:\\uploads\\";
      try {

              // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream

             File theDir = new File(destination);            
             if(!theDir.exists())
             {
                 try {
                    theDir.mkdir();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }            


    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));


              int read = 0;
              byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

              while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                  out.write(bytes, 0, read);
              }

              in.close();
              out.flush();
              out.close();           

              } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
              }
  }
```